# Reading data files with no data between delimiters

Tags: python, pandas

I have a data file that is pipe-delimited, but occasionally an empty value will not have data between two delimiters, leading to the delimiter character being placed in the corresponding column and later columns being populated with NaN values.

My code for creating my dataframes:

```
for DF_Exec in pd.read_table(ExecSrcFile, sep='|', chunksize=5000, header=1, low_memory=False, na_filter=True, index_col=False):
    # process data here
```

Each row in the file is 212 columns long, but I'll provide an example of what cases are not working

```
...|80|strdata|\x00|90.0| |...
```

These all work just fine. Spaces or null symbols between delimiters will be handled just fine.

```
...|80|strdata|||strdata|...
```

This will map to 4 columns, instead of 5, which causes null values in the last expected column. The 3rd column in this case only contains a `|` character.

A snippet of my actual data where this issue shows up:

```
...|0||||||USD|...
```

Because the file is very large, I would like to avoid the solution of processing it line by line to add spaces between the delimiters. Is there another more efficient option for dealing with this sort of issue using pandas or another package?

Comment: what kind of file are you trying to load? .txt, .csv, .xls, .xlsx, .dat??

Comment: The file is a giant block of pipe-delimited text

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using `pandas.read_csv(ExecSrcFile, sep='|')` ?

Comment: read_csv and read_table are the same function when you change the `sep` argument, and so both methods have the same problems.